# Liveness(Face antispoofing) detection by only one Photo. C#

Tags: c#, image-processing

I want to get to know whether the Person on the Photo is real person or not(Image, Mask, Picture on Camera etc.). I found several projects on github but all of them written in Python and they do not detect liveness with only one photo. How is it possible to write a program in C# to detect Face antispofing when my service recieves only one photo.

Appreciate any help:)

Comment: You can use OpenCV with C#. The most current methods use the training of some neural network for inference, but you can use common segmentation methods such as shape and border descriptors to solve some Presentation Attacks cases. See in this material there is a lot of reference about this art. https://christoph-busch.de/files/Busch-TelAviv-PAD-180116.pdf

Comment: You addressed two problems: face antispoofing with a single photo and C# code for face antispoofing. There are many antispoofing projects/repositories/papers but their accuracy in real life is pathetic. If you find a solution for that then conversion to C# code is easy.